# Importing Subclass sharing same directory of Superclass

Tags: python, oop, python-import, python-module

My file structure is like this:

```
- main.py
- components
-- __init__.py
-- Superclass.py
-- subclass.py
```

In **Superclass.py**:

```
class Superclass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

In **subclass.py**:

```
from Superclass import Superclass

class subclass(Superclass):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

In **main.py**:

```
from components import subclass
...
```

If I run **subclass.py** independently it gives expected result without any error.

But If I run **main.py** it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/../main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from components import subclass
   File "/../subclass.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Superclass import Superclass  
ImportError: No module named 'Superclass'
```

I am novice in OOP with python. I need to know why this error is happening and how to resolve this.

Comment: `from .Superclass import Superclass`?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. It works.